Why is this amine called this way?
I used a molecule drawing app to name the compound in the image, an amine. The name of the compound is 3-(aminomethyl)hexane according to the app. Shouldn't the name be 2-ethylpentan-1-amine?
The compound is clearly an amine, so it should have the ending -amine but the app names it as if it were a substituted alkane.
Isn't the parent chain supposed to be the longest chain that contains the functional group? The parent chain according to the app does not have the amino group directly attached to it, So, the main chain should be the one with 5 carbon atoms and the amino group attached to it, so the name should be what I said above.


The longest possible chain that contains the most number of substituents and functional groups in their respective priority orders. For example if the chain which contains say OH group is longer than the one with carboxylic acid, one should take the chain with the higher priority group ie carboxylic acid. So your point is correct. It could be due to a bug in the app.

Always first identify the longest continuous carbon chain!
In the case of 3-(aminomethyl)hexane, the longest continuous carbon chain is of 6, hence it ends with an hexane. In the case of 2-ethylpentan-1-amine, we see 'pent', which means it has 5 carbons in the continuous chain. As the longest possible continuous carbon chain is 6 carbons; therefore, we will have to go with the IUPAC name of 3-(aminomethyl)hexane, which adheres to the rule.
I hope this clarifies! In naming compounds always first identify the longest carbon chain, and then start naming.

The reference should be the original IUPAC source for nomenclature. See How to ask and answer nomenclature questions?

I removed the reference!
